# Are certain NOPAC routes reserved for military use?

Tags: military, navigation, flight-path

Are any Northern Pacific (NOPAC) routes reserved for military use?

Answer (score 2):

A local air force reserves chunks of its airspace as they see fit. But it never applies to publicly published inter-[FIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_information_region) routes. So the answer is no.

From *Fundamentals of Air Traffic Control* (on Google Books):

[image]

The routes stay out of Russian airspace, why that matters? Russia has a history of limiting civilian traffic through areas of their airspace. Like parts of the arctic circle, which only started to relax in the past decade or so.